Preventing Scroll Reset on Browser Navigation with Delayed Transition
I have a delay set up in my router config. I want to be able to click on the browser navigation buttons (back and forward) return to saved position, but since I have a delay and { left:0, top:0 }, it first jumps to top, then the delay happens and then I go to the previous route and see the saved position. I don’t want  { left:0, top:0 } to apply during transition when I press the browser buttons. But I want it to apply in all other cases, like for example, when I click on the router-link.
export const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition || to.query.page) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve({ left: 0, top: 0 });
                }, 400);
            });
        }
    },
});

Looking for a possible solution.

first, you must listen for navigation events and then apply the desired scroll behavior.

@ElsaKarami I just updated the question/title, because it wasn't clear enough. Does your answer still make sense for the updated question?

You can try to modify the scrollBehavior function in your router config to check whether the route navigation was triggered by the browser buttons (back and forward) or through any other means such as a router-link. You can use the from and to values to determine if the router was triggered by back or forward buttons by matching their fullPath.
